# How to set default schema through URL in SQLAlchemy.create_engine for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, schema, default, sqlacodegen

I tried to make a python models for my flask application with **sqlacodegen** .

and my database is postgresql in AWS_RDS .

so I tried like below

```
sqlacodegen postgresql://{RDS_USERNAME}:{RDS_PASSWORD}@{RDS_HOSTNAME}:{RDS_PORT}/{RDS_DB_NAME}'
```

but it just works with my default schema in postgresql **RDS_DB_NAME**

I want information of other schemas which are not set as default TT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved!!

I found that sqlacodegen has args option --schema

So, I made a commend as below

```
sqlacodegen --schema public_test URL
```